# SQL Custom unique Ordering with repeated sequence

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a datetime column (data type of `timestamp without time zone`) named `time`. I can best explain my issue with a example:

Example I've the following data in this column (pretifying timestamp for this example)

```
ID       TIME
1      1 Mar 2022 - 1PM
2      1 Mar 2022 - 2PM
3      1 Mar 2022 - 1PM
4      1 Mar 2022 - 3PM
5      1 Mar 2022 - 2PM
6      2 Mar 2022 - 2PM
7      2 Mar 2022 - 1PM
8      2 Mar 2022 - 3PM
9      2 Mar 2022 - 1PM
10     1 Mar 2022 - 3PM
11     2 Mar 2022 - 2PM
12     2 Mar 2022 - 3PM
13     3 Mar 2022 - 4PM
14     3 Mar 2022 - 3PM
15     3 Mar 2022 - 3PM
16     3 Mar 2022 - 4PM
```

If i do `ORDER BY time`, i get the following result:

```
ID       TIME
1      1 Mar 2022 - 1PM
3      1 Mar 2022 - 1PM
2      1 Mar 2022 - 2PM
5      1 Mar 2022 - 2PM
4      1 Mar 2022 - 3PM
10     1 Mar 2022 - 3PM
7      2 Mar 2022 - 1PM
9      2 Mar 2022 - 1PM
6      2 Mar 2022 - 2PM
11     2 Mar 2022 - 2PM
8      2 Mar 2022 - 3PM
12     2 Mar 2022 - 3PM
14     3 Mar 2022 - 3PM
15     3 Mar 2022 - 3PM
13     3 Mar 2022 - 4PM
16     3 Mar 2022 - 4PM
```

But i want the result in this way:

```
ID       TIME
1      1 Mar 2022 - 1PM
2      1 Mar 2022 - 2PM
4      1 Mar 2022 - 3PM
13     3 Mar 2022 - 4PM
3      1 Mar 2022 - 1PM
5      1 Mar 2022 - 2PM
10     1 Mar 2022 - 3PM
16     3 Mar 2022 - 4PM
7      2 Mar 2022 - 1PM
6      2 Mar 2022 - 2PM
8      2 Mar 2022 - 3PM
9      2 Mar 2022 - 1PM
11     2 Mar 2022 - 2PM
12     2 Mar 2022 - 3PM
14     3 Mar 2022 - 3PM
13     3 Mar 2022 - 4PM
```

As you can see first 4 rows have unique timestamp and the sequence should repeat based on Time (1PM, 2PM, 3PM).

How can we do this in SQL? I'm using postresql as my DB. I'm using Rails for my Backend.

EDIT:
Have added more context to example to explain my scenario.

Comment: You should have defined that column with the **data type** `time` then the sorting would be correct automatically. Never store date or time values in `text` or `varchar` columns. Do you have a chance to fix that broken data model before proceeding?

Comment: No, I need datetime only. Above is example so just included time. How would you do if it's just a time data type? As far as i know, time data type `ORDER BY` will do `1PM, 1PM, 1PM, 2PM, 2PM, 2PM, 3PM, 3PM, 3PM`

Comment: "datetime" is a date **and** a time, e.g. `2022-03-30 15:30`. Your sample data only shows a "time", not a "datetime". What exactly is the data type of that column? Please **[edit]** your question and add the `create table` statement of the table in question ([formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557))

Comment: Note that `11PM` < `2PM`, when using character data types.

Comment: I'm using rails, so have a convention of just saying `datetime`. I've added datatype and more context to my question.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can try to use `ROW_NUMBER` window function with `REPLACE` function

```
SELECT time
FROM (
  SELECT *,REPLACE(time,'PM','') val,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY REPLACE(time,'PM','')) rn
  FROM T
) t1
ORDER BY rn,val
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have at hand is a direct result of not choosing the correct data type for the values you store.

To get the sorting correct, you need to convert the string to a proper `time` value. There is no `to_time()` function in Postgres, but you can convert it to a `timestamp` then cast it to a `time`:

```
order by to_timestamp("time", 'hham')::time
```

You should fix your database design and convert that column to a proper `time` type. Which will also prevent storing invalid values (`'3 in the afternoon'` or `'128foo'`) in that column

Answer (score 0):

For example, sequence of the col a

```
with tbl(a, othercol) as
( 
   SELECT 1,1  UNION ALL
   SELECT 1,2  UNION ALL
   SELECT 1,3  UNION ALL
   SELECT 2,4  UNION ALL
   SELECT 2,5  UNION ALL
   SELECT 2,6  UNION ALL
   SELECT 3,7  UNION ALL
   SELECT 3,8  UNION ALL
   SELECT 3,9  
),
   cte as (
   SELECT *, row_number() over(partition by a order by a) rn
   from tbl
)
select a, othercol
from cte
order by rn, a
```